# How to create and update referenced documents with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this setup

```
var NotesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    category: [{  type: mongoose.ObjectId, ref: "Categories", default: [] }],
},{ timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });
var CategoriesSchema = new Schema({
    name: {type: String, required: true}
})

var Notes = mongoose.model('Notes', NotesSchema);
var Cat = mongoose.model('Categories', CategoriesSchema);
```

If I want to create a new note and categories I do this

```
.get('/new', async (req, res) => {
    var post1=  {
        title : "Post: books, thriller, crime and classics",      
        favorite : true,
        categories:[ 'thriller', 'books']
    } 
    try{ 
        var note = post1.categories.map(  (cat)=>{
            var ca = new Cat({name: cat})
            ca.save()
            return ca._id
        })
        post1.category = note 
        const newNote = new Notes(post1);
        const n = await newNote.save()
        res.send(n)
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
    }; 
})
```

If I were to create a new note that has some new categories I'm stuck.

```
var post1=  {
       ...
        categories:[ 'thriller', 'books', 'classics']
    }
```

'thriller' and 'books' already exist, but 'classics' doesn't.

I tried `Cat.find({"name": {$in: post1.categories}}).exec()` but I can't seem to look through that data.

All the example tutorials seem to just add one new entry at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `post1.categories.map` callback you are creating the Cat documents and call `save()` on them but you do not await the returned promise. So `Note` is created before those promises are fulfilled and thus `post1.category` will be an empty array.

You can fix this by awaiting the save-promises of the categories:

```
const savePromises = post1.categories.map((cat) => {
    const ca = new Cat({name: cat})
    return ca.save();
})

const categoryIds = (await Promise.all(savePromises)).map(category => category._id);

post1.category = categoryIds;
// rest of your code
```